# Javascript is slow in IE 8

Tags: javascript, performance, razorengine

I am having Performance issue with IE 8 (Mvc4, razor view engine). I have googled a couple of sites. But nothing sounds helpful. This performance issue exists only in IE and it works fast in Mozilla and Chrome. I have also found the culprit. But sadly, I dunno how to fix it.

Below mentioned are the details :

### Scenario

I am looping through the rows of a dataset and creating dropdownlist dynamically.

```
 <td class="sort"> @Html.DropDownList("chillernames" + i,

(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["Chillernew"], new { @class = "drpdwn", onchange = "test(" + i + ")" })</td>
```

To set the selected value,I am calling the javascript function as follows :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var chk = @i
        $(document.getElementById("chillernames" + chk)).find('option[value="@Model.Array_Flightdockdet[i, 7]"]').prop('selected', true);
     });
</script>
```

where `i` is my looping variable. I honestly don't understand why this script slows down the performance dramatically in IE 8.

Comment: Do you know how jQuery works? Why are you using `document.getElementById("chillernames" + chk)` inside the jQuery selector?

Comment: Find out which statement is slow in IE8. Maybe we can give you an alternative.

Comment: as putvande said, use jQuery: $("#chillernames"+chk).find ...  ; ALSO note that the latest version of jQ does not support IE 8, only the older jQuery 1.x branch supports it...

Comment: @putvande: Ofcourse I do know. I am using document.getElement bcz native search is fast than using "#". I have read articles on it and yeah it did showed the difference. Adding '$' allowed me to use jquery functionalities.

Comment: @Frits : The script that i am using to set the selected value of a dropwdown list is what slowing down the performance.

Comment: @Blasius: I am usinh 1.7.1 :(

Comment: @LittleSweet: Yes but whats the way to fix it?